# Query Issue for joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql

This Query is not Run.. Please solve this problem..

```
select q.id,q.name,qq.text 
from quiz q,quiz_question qq 
where qq.quiz_id='1'
```

table:

```
quiz
   id,name
quiz_question
   id,quiz_id,text
```

Comment: We don't have any algorithm to decipher what you want, please kindly most more info!

Comment: If you are joining two tables there should be common column.

Comment: You have to set one more condition for joining the tables like `q.id=qq.quiz_id`

Comment: @HDK: if your problem is resolved. consider accepting best answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's is no problem with your query. I bet it will run but have wrong result. You are `cross` *joining* the table. I think you want:

```
select q.id, q.name, qq.text 
from   quiz q,quiz_question qq 
where qq.quiz_id = '1' AND
      q.id=qq.quiz_id
```

but **better** do this

```
select q.id, q.name, qq.text 
from   quiz q INNER JOIN quiz_question qq 
           on q.id=qq.quiz_id
where  qq.quiz_id = '1'
```

and one more thing, if your **id** is `number` then you **shouldn't wrap** it with single quote.

```
select q.id, q.name, qq.text 
from   quiz q INNER JOIN quiz_question qq 
           on q.id=qq.quiz_id
where  qq.quiz_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select q.id,q.name,qq.text 
from quiz q inner join quiz_question qq on q.id = qq.quiz_id
where q.quiz_id='1';
```

OR

```
select q.id,q.name,qq.text 
from quiz q inner join quiz_question qq on q.id = qq.quiz_id and q.quiz_id='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use legacy SQL syntax. If you want to join tables use an expiclit `join`

```
select q.id, q.name, qq.text 
from quiz q
inner join quiz_question qq on q.id = qq.quiz_id
where q.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is join the tables together, on the `quiz_id`.

This can be done as:

```
 SELECT
  q.id,q.name,
  qq.text
 FROM
  quiz q
  INNER JOIN quiz_question qq ON ( q.id = qq.quiz_id )
 WHERE
  q.id = 1
```